# Perlin Noise' gradient

Tags: mathematics, perlin-noise

I'm having some problem understanding the Perlin Noise algorithm and none of the explanation I found go into this (probably obvious)detail.

From what function is the gradient on it? Is it from the blending function?

Comment: No idea what the question is.

Comment: If you are aware of what the Perlin Noise algorithm you know it uses a gradient. But on all implementations they use a pre computed table for the gradient and I don't understand from what was the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient is between the dot products of vectors to corners and randomly chosen vectors.

The pre-computed table you are looking at is likely part of the hash-function. (used to generate random numbers in a way that stays constant between calls)